# Is the coast of england a platonic form?

Tags: metaphysics, plato

A real-world circle is not a true circle which, as far as Platos concerned, lives in the World of Forms. But isn't a fractal a mathematical form, so that does live in the the World of Forms; and as Mandelbrot pointed out, the coast of England, the shape of a cloud and the shape of a fern are fractals so they too live in the World of Forms?

Going further, isn't the standard model when expressed geometrically a form so that too lives there, and its consequences are too, so the universe itself is in the World of Forms; doesn't this then involve a infinite regress?

Comment: What is a mathematical form, as distinct from any other form?

Comment: Hmm. Can you tell us a little more about the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @Weissmann:I'm trying to understand the implications of Platos World of Forms have. Generally when I've read about this, the usual example of a Platonic form has been a circle, presumably all the other platonic solids qualify. Their qualifying attribute is a simple synthetic geometric description. I think all these can be expanded, what do mean by simple and by geometry (by synthetic, I mean not involving coordinates). The question at its most basic level - What did Plato mean by a Form.

Comment: @Beaudrap: Good question, I'm not sure, but I'd hestitate to say all forms are mathematical. For the purposes of this question, I'm saying mathematical forms qualify as Platonic forms, going by Platos example of the circle.

Comment: @Weissman: Perhaps I should first understand what problem Plato is trying to solve with his World of FOrms, is he alluding to an underlying mathematical reality, or an ontology for mathematics.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: I am not sure what books are you reading that use a circle as an example of a Platonic form; in my reading, the canonical example has always been the Horse.  There's no reason to view Platonic ideals as necessarily geometrical-- I think that is only confusing matters.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: so, if someone were to come up with a parameterized formula which described the average coastline of England to a precision of one meter --- or described an iterative procedure to yield a fractal shape which to good precision matched the coastline of England after a few iterations --- would this not imply that the coastline of England is in some sense a mathematical form? Is the status of being a mathematical form a function of time, possibly depending on human effort or intent?

Comment: @Dorfman: I think I was going on hearsay & my imagination rather than the primary source, or a good secondary one. I see your point.

Comment: @Beaudrap: Well the geometric curve _describes_ the the shape of the coastline well, but it _itself_ isn't the the coastline; further, its mathematical description doesn't include the essence of a coastline, which is, it separates land from sea.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: nor does a circle contain the essence of the outline of a circular pie, which is that it separates the crust from the medium (such as air) which surrounds it. It all depends on how much of the object you would like your Platonic ideal to capture, I suppose. Is there no Platonic form of 'circle', perhaps, because different instances of circular shapes play somewhat different roles in the physical circumstances in which they find themselves?

Comment: @Beaudrap: I think so. It does look more complicated than I first thought, and it probably means I'll have to delve into Platos writings to find out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coast of England cannot be a Platonic Form- at best it can be the flawed image of a Form that exists within space and time.

One can ask if there is Form that the coast of England reflects? And in this case is that Form the Form of Fractal? Would this even be a Form?

Seeing as traditional examples of Forms involve specific shapes ie- that of a Horse, a Chair, or a *certain* geometric shape (circle, square, cube, etc) I would argue that "Fractal" would not in and of itself be a Form as many different fractals have many different shapes. Note that there is no Form = Geometric Plane Figure. That level of abstractness appears to absent from the concept of Forms if read in the sense in which they were written.

No. The coast of England is a representation of the Form "Coast" as well it should be. A Coast being the Form that can be seen as separating Forms Land and Sea.

Comment: If there is no form called "geometric plane figure" (why?), then why do you not allow the coast of England correspond to a *particular* fractal which is a Platonic Form, which we happen not to have named? Surely the Platonic realm does have *some* examples of forms which are fractals, such as Cantor's Dust and the Sierpinksi Triangle. Under what conditions is some one particular fractal, or other form, recognised as a Platonic form? (For instance, is there a separate Zebra form in addition to the Horse form?)

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap correct. There is a Horse Form and perhaps a Zebra Form- but there is no "Fractal" form. And if the shape of the English Coast is unchanging then it would be a Form- but not of Fractal- that of the English Coast- yet it changes doesn't it? I'm just arguing as Plato- clearly there is inconstancy.

Comment: Does it matter which name I give it? Not that it matters, as it would seem clear that an appropriate name for the Platonic Form in question is "Coast Of England".

Comment: No. the Coast of England changes- it cannot as per definition be a Form. That is clear. Read about Forms. I indicated this in my last comment- not sure how else to say it. I mean Plato is not here to argue with

Comment: No, you're talking about "the coast of England", which is indeed a changeable and imperfect representation of The Coast Of England. However, I do take your point about the fact that Plato isn't here to argue with... anything we might have to say about his forms is enitrely speculative, unless we are able to argue logically from his works what his opinion must be. Which I don't think you have. (Not that I'm trying to...)

Comment: I see what you are saying but you have stepped well outside the world of Platonic Forms. Indeed you have shown an error in their deduction- as such you step outside the question

Comment: @jaskey: I'm a little confused as to why you say that as the coast of england changes, it cannot be a form; the standard example of a form, from platos book is a horse, and that changes; it grows, it gets old, it dies.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to understand Mandelbrot's claim is: the coast of England *can be profitably modelled as* a fractal (for some purposes). It's exactly the same kind of claim as "The granma pie at Luigi's is a rectangle".

So, no: the coast of England is not literally a fractal, and it's not in the world of forms -- it's actually in England :)

Comment: Of course, a fractal has infinite resolution :).

Comment: @MoziburUllah for example, yes. Also, a fractal has no spatio-temporal location, and is not made of atoms. All of these things are false of the coast of England. In short, a fractal is an _abstract entity_, and the coast of England is not. Talk of _abstract entities_ is less misleading, I think, than talk of Platonic Forms (if you are more interested in metaphysics than in Plato scholarship, that is).

Comment: @Martinez: Sure, but don't atoms too have a mathematical description? Of course your point still holds, since a model of some thing is not the thing itself. I'm not saying the coast of england is itself in the World of Forms; if I was being careful, rather than allowing a little leeway for rhetoric, I would have said the shape of the coast of england, in the same way I said the shape of a cloud is in the World of Forms.

Comment: *"It's exactly the same kind of claim as 'The granma pie at Luigi's is a rectangle'"* --- this doesn't suffice to resolve the issue in itself. One can ask whether *a particular fractal* which models well England's coastline is in the Platonic realm, given that the Platonic realm is undoubtedly meant to contain several rectangles or other quadrilaterals which model well the granma pie.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Yes, I have nothing particularly insightful to say regarding what would have Plato thought of fractals. I honestly thought Mozibur was asking for the relation between abstract and concrete entities.

Comment: @Beaudrap: I think now my question could have been better phrased - perhaps along the lines as to whether any modern philosopher has addressed how the forms discussed in mathematical world fit in, _if they do_, in Platos World of Forms. (With the provisio, that not all Forms are of a geometric nature).

Comment: @Martinez: see above.

Comment: @MoziburUllah, well, you can always edit your question.